# Abort request while navigating away from the component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

I am using `react`, `redux` and `react-router`. One of my page is making an API request and showing the data. It works fine. What I want to know is, if the API request is not yet finished, and the user navigates to another route, I want to be able to abort the request.

I am assuming I should dispatch some action in the `componentWillUnmount`. Just not able to understand how will it work. Something like...

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.dispatch(Actions.abortRequest());
}
```

And I'll store the `xhr` reference somewhere in the action. Not sure if this is the correct approach or not (I think not), can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think storing `xhr` in action is correct.
Actions should be serializable, and XMLHttpRequest definitely isn't.

Instead, I'd use [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) to return a custom object from my action creator, and do something like this:

```
function fetchPost(id) {
  return dispatch => {
    // Assuming you have a helper to make requests:
    const xhr = makePostRequest(id);

    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_POST_REQUEST', response, id });

    // Assuming you have a helper to attach event handlers:
    trackXHR(xhr,
      (response) => dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_POST_SUCCESS', response, id }),
      (err) => dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_POST_FAILURE', err, id })
    );

    // Return an object with `abort` function to be used by component
    return { abort: () => xhr.abort() };     
  };
}
```

Now you can use `abort` from your component:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.requests = [];
  this.requests.push(
    this.props.dispatch(fetchPost(this.props.postId))
  );
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.requests.forEach(request => request.abort());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with this approach. What you're holding in the `store` is the global application state; if you want to change the `xhr` behaviour based on other actions then you need to store that state somewhere.

I've seen plenty of examples where the store would look something like this:

```
{
  isFetching: false,
  items: [],
  lastUpdated: null
};
```

The `isFetching` state is then used to display a loading spinner or prevent multiple `xhr` requests being sent. I'd see your use and storing the `xhr` reference and being able to abort it is just an extension of this.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking if there can be a more generic way of doing this. Something like a global React hook that gets executed every time a component is unmount. This way I'm not enforcing the developers who write different components to clean up their stuff on each component.