# dispatch(action) doesn't immediately update redux state in unit tests

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, redux

I am writing test cases for my application bases on react and redux.

```
container = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
  <Provider store={createStore({"key": "old_val"})}>
    {() => <Component />}
  </Provider>
);
```

After rendering with `initialState`, I dispatch an action and see if the state changes.

```
Component.store.dispatch({ type: 'SET_VAL', value: 'some_val' });
```

Then I print the state

```
console.log(store.getState());
```

I expect the state to be `{"key": "some_val"}`. However, it still shows `{"key": "old_val"}`.

The application works fine, just not the test, so there can't be any problem with my `action-creators` or `reducers`.

Am I doing something wrong here? Btw, I am using `thunk` middleware for async action dispatch. Does that interfere here? If yes, how do I wait till the async action gets completed?

**Update:**

The redux tests [shown here](https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/test/createStore.spec.js) are pretty straightforward, yet they seem to work fine.

```
store.dispatch(addTodo('Hello'));
expect(store.getState()).toEqual([{
  id: 1,
  text: 'Hello'
}]);
```

Comment: Have you considered testing your action creators and reducers without setting up React? Both action creators and reducers are just pure functions so it is really easy to call them on their own and verify the output. If you'd like I can write an answer to demonstrate.

Comment: O yes, I realized I missed this point in the Q, so added. Though I haven't yet added tests for action creators and reducers, but they work fine and I have verified.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you need to verify that the plumbing of `react-redux` is working in your application's tests. One of the intentions of having `react-redux` as a separate library is that you can test your reducers and action creators in isolation. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I am rendering some info in my Component based on the state. So just need to write the test to verify if the rendered text changes when I change the state. But you have a point, if I test individual units, the overall functionality should work just fine.

Comment: Since state is passed as `props` to your `connect`ed components it is the responsibility of `react` and `react-redux` to ensure that updates are propagated to your component. If you need to test component output based on a change in state you can actually just pass in test state as `props` and work with the component in isolation as well. Components are pure(-ish) functions of state in a similar manner to reducers and action creators so the same ideas apply.

Comment: That was one awesome explanation. I think it'll be helpful for others as well if you post that as an answer and we'll close this thread. Anyway, I'm convinced that I shouldn't test that part. But still curious why it doesn't update immediately? And how do you find out when it got updated.

Comment: Sounds great! Glad I was able to help. I've been doing a lot of redux unit testing this week and wanted to pass along some lessons learned.

Comment: Oh! I also just noticed that your call to `createStore` is passing an initial state without a reducer. The first argument should be the reducer and the second the initial state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the huge benefits of redux is that it allows you to implement almost all of your application using pure functions and pure components. Redux and react-redux abstract the implementation details of subscribing UI to state changes which allows you to test all of your app's code in isolation. This way you don't need to render out a provider with a store every time you want to test out your code, which is a major reduction in complexity.

Let's say you have a `key` property in your state and a `KeyDisplay` component. You can implement the state with the following reducer file:

**reducers.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

export function key(state, { type, value }) {
  switch(type) {
    case 'SET_VAL': return value;
    default: return state;
  }
}

export default combineReducers({ key });
```

And you can set up a file for our component:

**KeyDisplay.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export function KeyDisplay({ keyProp }) {
  return (
    <div>The key is {keyProp}</div>
  );
}

export default connect((state) => { keyProp: state.key })(KeyDisplay);
```

Then in the unit test for the reduce you can import just the reducer for `key` and test it totally separate of the user interface:

**keyReducer.test.js**

```
import test from 'tape';
import { key } from './reducers.js';

test('key reducer', (t) => {
  t.plan(1);
  const output = key('old', { type: 'SET_VAL', value: 'new' });
  t.equal(output, 'new', 'SET_VAL should override old value');
});
```

Additionally, since `connect` passes state as props into the component you can just render the un`connect`ed component with some test props that represent a state you are interested in, again without setting up a store and provider:

**KeyDisplay.test.js**

```
import test from 'tape';
import { renderIntoDocument } from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import { KeyDisplay } from './KeyDisplay.js';

test('KeyDisplay', (t) => {
  const component = renderIntoDocument(<KeyDisplay keyProp="test" />);
  // test component
});
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks. Since you're so good in `redux`, I was wondering if you could have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32901466/1520671) question as well. I didn't really get a satisfactory solution to that I feel.

Comment: I have to agree with Dan on that one, that's how I would do it as well. If you have deeper questions about different scenarios with Redux I definitely suggest getting in touch with Dan if you can, he did create the library after all ;)